# Error inserting row into table

Tags: wpdb, table

I am trying to insert a row into a table.

Given below are the various functions to create table. insert data into the table- but its not working. Also given below is the sample output showing all fields that are being attempted to be inserted.

```
/* Function: Insert Zillow property data into table
* Input: $zillowid String, $date DateTime
* Output: Boolean
*/
function zillowInsertData($zillowid, $date_val, $postid, $url) {
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->base_prefix."Zillow";
if(trim($date_val) == '')
    $date_val= string2DateTime("0000-00-00");
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO $table_name (ZillowID, PostID, PropertyURL, DateUpdated)
    VALUES ($zillowid, $postid, $url,$date_val)";
return $wpdb->query($sql)===1;
}

echo " Values being inserted- 
    Zp id=" . $current_zpid . ", 
    postid=" . $post_id, "url=" . $propertyurl;
zillowInsertData($current_zpid, "", $post_id, $propertyurl );
```

Sample output showing values being inserted into the table-

```
About to insert row in Zillow table 
Values being inserted- 
    Zp id=51605333, 
    postid=111
    url=http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1457-Golf-Course-Dr-Windsor-CA-95492/51605333_zpid/
```

Table creation code--

```
global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->base_prefix."Zillow";
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name(
        ZillowID text NOT NULL, PostID text NOT NULL,
        PropertyURL text, 
        DateUpdated datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL
    );";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update-- The string2datetime function uses strtotime php function.

Thanks,
Arvind.

Comment: can you provide the error message(s) that appear?

Comment: 1) What does `string2DateTime()` return?  Is there a compelling reason to not use native PHP functions like [`date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 0 );`](http://php.net/date)?  2) `$wpdb->base_prefix` is useful in Multisite if you want to tell `$wpdb` to use the root site's tables.  If you want to add to the current site's tables -- or if you're not using Multisite -- you should use `$wpdb->prefix` instead.

Comment: @PatJ I have updated the post. Also,  I can use $wpdb->prefix, but in other functions also I am using base_prefix and its working(I understand your point- but that is not the problem here)

Comment: @guiniveretoo could you let me know how to output the error message? Do you want me to directly run the query in DB(after echoing it from the function just before the function runs that query)? Or would you suggest some way of getting the error from $wpdb->query? How would I do that? THanks

Comment: [wpdb: Show and Hide SQL errors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors)

Comment: "Do you want me to directly run the query in DB(after echoing it from the function just before the function runs that query)?" <-- I do that for tricky queries. I find it easier to edit, but it should not be necessary just to see the errors.